# Problem building driver for UVC camera

Tags: software-installation

When I was trying to install a driver for a UVC camera, I got an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/libpthread.so.0 inside 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a inside 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [capture_mux] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/me4_x86-tot-44324/me4_x86-sdk/sw/64380/mxuvc/examples'
make[3]: *** [build_bin] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/me4_x86-tot-44324/me4_x86-sdk/sw/64380/mxuvc'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/me4_x86-tot-44324/me4_x86-sdk/sw/64380/mxuvc'
make[1]: *** [mxuvc/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/me4_x86-tot-44324/me4_x86-sdk/sw/64380'
make: *** [buildall] Error 2
```

My first step was:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/me4_x86-tot-44324/me4_x86-sdk/sw$ make defconfig PRODUCT_TYPE=me4_x86
Installing Package ------------ > kernel-devel 
No package with kernel-devel package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > kernel 
No package with kernel package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > libdaemon-devel 
No package with libdaemon-devel package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > expat-devel 
No package with expat-devel package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > avahi-devel 
No package with avahi-devel package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > fcgi-devel 
No package with fcgi-devel package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > lighttpd 
No package with lighttpd package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > alsa-lib-devel 
No package with alsa-lib-devel package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > alsa-utils 
No package with alsa-utils package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > libcurl-devel
No package with libcurl-devel package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > udev 
No package with udev package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > libusb1-devel 
No package with libusb1-devel package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > libusb1-static 
No package with libusb1-static package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > glibc-static 
No package with glibc-static package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > gcc 
No package with gcc package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > gcc-c++ 
No package with gcc-c++ package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > doxygen 
No package with doxygen package present in repositories
Installing Package ------------ > openssl-devel 
No package with openssl-devel package present in repositories
Setting default config for me4_x86
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/me4_x86-tot-44324/me4_x86-sdk/sw/host_sdk'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `defconfig'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/me4_x86-tot-44324/me4_x86-sdk/sw/host_sdk'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/me4_x86-tot-44324/me4_x86-sdk/sw/buildroot'
mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/me4_x86-tot-44324/me4_x86-sdk/sw/buildroot/output/build/buildroot-config
#
# configuration written to /home/ubuntu/me4_x86-tot-44324/me4_x86-sdk/sw/buildroot/.config
#
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/me4_x86-tot-44324/me4_x86-sdk/sw/buildroot'
```

Comment: What was it you was trying to install?

Comment: It was an driver for uvc-camera

Comment: Could you provide a link to the driver, the type of system you are using(32bit/64bit) and the details about the camera. at best you need to install the 32bit libraries, but, thats if your lucky. If your not lucky you will enter dependencies hell. **Note** preferably edit your question and add details

Comment: I cant give you a link for this and the name of the camera...Im using 32bit system

Comment: I only need the libralys... I think so

Comment: Try some of the packages here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=glibc+&searchon=names&suite=saucy&section=all

Comment: to install it via the terminal `sudo apt-get install clisp`

Comment: Ok I will try it.

Comment: doesn't help....

Comment: One other you could try: `sudo apt-get install eglibc` and also don't forget to run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I have installed all this packages

Comment: And? No build error?

Comment: Nope, there is one, the same error

Comment: Try the following: `sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential` it, apparently, installs all the needed packages for building

Comment: If that doesn't help, see this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: may when I do the first step there is an error:

Comment: Which step may that be?

Comment: Its a little toooooo long :D for a comment

Comment: ... Edit your question.... :D

Comment: So its edited now

Comment: In first step is no problem, I was trying the same on my twice machine, and the first step works fine...

Comment: Which step gives the above error?

Comment: Also the main error comes after the second step/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/libpthread.so.0 inside 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a inside 
and more, you can read in at the topic header :)

Comment: the error with this library: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound I did resolve.. but the next two /usr/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/libpthread.so.0 inside 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a inside I cant find them

Comment: Am not on my Ubuntu machine right now, so can't really try to compile it myself. But, you can try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UVC#Installing_UVC. and if that doesn't work, as an alternative, try: [Cheese Webcam studio](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cheese/)

Comment: Did you did `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-\`uname -r\``?

Comment: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` dont helps, and the normal uvc driver I cant install... its a specifically camera with RTMP/RTSP steam and more...

Comment: Please move this to chat.

Comment: Where can I found this "Chat"?